# .sh script doesn't increment variable

Tags: dockerfile, sh

I wrote this script to be executed via a Dockerfile. I have tried many syntaxes for increasing the variable by one but it doesn't seem to evaluate.

I've tried...(($iteration++))...iteration=$iteration+1...

```sh
iteration=0
max_iteration=5

server_init()
{
    echo 'start.sh executing'
    if curl --fail -X GET http://0.0.0.0:5000/dev/api/development/ping; then
        # …(success)
        curl -X GET http://0.0.0.0:5000/dev/api/development/seed_stocks
    else
        # …(failure)
        echo 'Python server ping failed - repinging in 5s'
        sleep 5
        iteration=$(($iteration+1))
        if ["$iteration" -lt "$max_iteration"]; then 
            server_init
        else
            echo 'Max iterations reached -- Stopping start.sh recursion'
        fi;
    fi;
}

server_init
```

The above script evaluates to...

```
./tmp/start.sh: 15: [1: not found
```

Comment: You need _spaces_ inside your brackets - see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117438.

Comment: `[` is the name of a command, not syntax.